# How to find orders of elements in a vector in which duplicate elements have the same order?

Tags: r, sorting

I have a vector `x = [5, 5, 3, 2, 2]`. The rank of an element is its position in the *descending* list of *unique* values. I would like to return the vector contains the rank of each element, i.e `[1, 1, 2, 3, 3]`. Unfortunately, the function `order` does not do the job.

```
x <- c(5, 5, 3, 2, 2)
order(x)
```

and the result is

```
[1] 4 5 3 1 2
```

Could you please elaborate on how to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1) factor** Convert to a factor having the indicated levels and then convert to numeric to get the level numbers:

```
as.numeric(factor(x, levels = unique(x)))
## [1] 1 1 2 3 3
```

**2) match** Another possibility is to use `match`:

```
match(x, unique(x))
## [1] 1 1 2 3 3
```

**3) findInterval**  `findInterval` requires non-descending numbers in the second argument so we negate x.

```
findInterval(-x, unique(-x))
## [1] 1 1 2 3 3
```

**4) diff/cumsum**

```
cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(x) != 0))
## [1] 1 1 2 3 3
```

**5) rle**

```
r <- rle(x)
r$values <- seq_along(r$values)
inverse.rle(r)
## [1] 1 1 2 3 3
```

### Note

The input in R syntax is:

```
x <- c(5, 5, 3, 2, 2)
```

Comment: The second solution does not work for `row <- c(4, 18, 15,  3,  1,  2,  0,  1, 19,  0, 14)` and `match(row, unique(row))`. Could you please have a check on it?

Comment: The question says the values are descending so that is not a valid input.

Comment: Oh I mean "descending list of unique values" by the sorted list containing only unique values.

Comment: It is not clear what "desecnding list of unique values" means but I have added 2 more solutions to the original problem which may or may be what you need for the revixed problem. They start out with 1 and increase the value by 1 each time a value changes from the immediately prior value.